# AWS amplify Can't resolve '@aws-amplify/core'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

As the title suggests, when I run `npm start` in my project folder the I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@aws-amplify/core' in '/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/react-amplified/node_modules/@aws-amplify/api/lib-esm'
```

The project is literally the template code created by `npx create-react-app react-amplified cd react-amplified`

I tried installing @aws-amplify/core directly but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/installation/q/integration/react#option-1-watch-the-video-guide

When scaffolding a new react app, there are a few steps beyond `npx create-react-app` that need to be run to `Amplify` your project.

1. `amplify configure` to setup your amplify cli
2. `amplify init` to initialize your backend resources in AWS.

Comment: Thank you so much! The tutorials I went through didn't mention I had to configure & initialize amplify.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: You bet. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `amplify init`? Look at the docs and install all the dependencies. https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/js?sc_icampaign=start&sc_ichannel=docs-home

Comment: At least a link to the docs would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with using amplify 4 with npm 7 hoisting and has a PR here https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/pull/8368

Comment: thanks for sharing! I was really confused since I'd followed their tutorial exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with Amplify 4 and NPM 7. Using yarn fixed this issue for me!